# Can I get the Tweet ID from the TWTweetComposeViewController class?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, twitter

It seems like it isn't possible to get the tweet ID from `TWTweetComposeViewController`. If this is the case, should I make the user tweet in some other way so I can get the tweet ID?

I need it in order to create replies to a tweet.

Also, is it possible to add the tweet id in the tweet?

Answer (score 0):

The `TWTweetComposeViewController` class only has the following public properties/methods:

```
+ canSendTweet
– setInitialText:
– addImage:
– addURL:
– removeAllImages
– removeAllURLs
completionHandler
```

[TWTweetComposeViewController Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)

All of the user's social account information (Facebook & Twitter) is stored in `ACAccount`.

[Apple ACAccount Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011019)